# Dynamically change menu according to user role in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I want to display different menu according to login user . If user is client then display different menu otherwise show different menu.

I have one table User which is used to authenticate user , Client table which hold the userId as foreign key . Then how we determine whether user is client or not?

Another there is any way to add controller for menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best ways would be to use Spring Security plugin. Once setup (which is easy and there is good documentation around) you can control content based on user/roles in a couple ways:

- In the controller - pass different menu options to the view based on the output of `ifAllGraanted('ROLE_ADMIN')` function
- Directly in the view - `<sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">`

More info here: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html